# Active cell address

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i get the Cell address from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628603/how-can-i-get-the-cell-address-from-excel)

Is it possible to get active cell address like  A1048576 in excel using vsto or c# or any hint using vba.

I am able to get active cell rows and columns but it shows integer values ,i want cell address like A10 or B15

Comment: [`cell.Address()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174749%28v=office.11%29.aspx)?

Comment: possible repeat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628603/how-can-i-get-the-cell-address-from-excel