# VSTO Display Selected Cell Reference in Text Box

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a Windows Form with a list of values to display each with a corresponding text box that tells the program what cell to display it in. Currently the user inputs a range (ex. "A1", "G6", etc...) for each value they want shown and leave the remaining blank.

Is there any way to click into the text box, and then click in a cell and have that cell reference appear in the text box (like how Goal Seek works)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your VSTO code, you should be able to handle the Worksheet [SelectionChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.selectionchange.aspx) event

For example, in a VSTO project we own, we subscribe to the OnChange event of each worksheet at startup:

```
  private List<Excel.Worksheet> _Worksheets = new List<Excel.Worksheet>();

  private void ThisWorkbook_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
   foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in Worksheets) //Could test for sheet name here
   {
    _Worksheets.Add(sheet);
    sheet.SelectionChange += 
        new Excel.DocEvents_SelectionChangeEventHandler(Sheet_SelectionChange);
   }
  }
```

You should be able to then get the ActiveCell in your handler, something like:

```
Excel.Range activeCell = (Excel.Range) this.Application.ActiveCell;

//get the cell value (or other properties)
object value = rng.Value;
```

Once you have a reference to the cell, you can get the address by using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2630016/1073107).

You should then be able to update the value of your textbox.