# Get actual cell in Worksheet using interop

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm working with a project where I use interop to work with Excel. I have a full Worksheet and I would like to know how can I get the name cell, for example, **B15**.

I'm trying to do it with this:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < RowsCount; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
                    {
                        object cellValue = rng.Value;
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*****value is: " + cellValue.ToString());
                    }
                }
```

But doesn't work. I'm new with interop and I am trying to find good tutorials but can't find a good one.
**At the end, what I want to do is introduce formulas in some cells.
For that reason, I need to know the actual cell and the limits of the Excel, the last row and column.**

To know the last row or column, Can I know it with the worksheet or have I know it with the datatable used to create the actual worksheet?

Comment: Cells got a property called `Address`. It returns what you want, but I do not know how to call it from C#, so that's the reason I post this as a comment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.address?view=excel-pia

Comment: A decent Google query is "excel interop get cell address".  Takes you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628603/how-can-i-get-the-cell-address-from-excel).

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns but I don't know what put in "missing", nothing?

Comment: I don't know C#. Test it and try to get it, but the answer works and does exactly what you want

Comment: This method works @HansPassant but if the index is 0 give me an error, why could be?