# C# Replace text within double quote

Tags: c#

This is my first post in this forum. I have text with in double which i want to replace by another text.

This is my full text

**"Operational Metrics~Copper C1 Cash Costs (US$/lb) - Lalor~9999"*"Operational Metrics~Canadian Dollars (Canadian $/US$)~9999"**

This text **"Operational Metrics~Copper C1 Cash Costs (US$/lb) - Lalor~9999"** will be replace with excel cell address **A10**.

I have tried this way but not being able to replace the text within double quote. surely there is problem in my code which i am not able to fix.

```
string mainstr = "\"" + "Operational Metrics~Copper C1 Cash Costs (US$/lb) - Lalor~9999" + "\"" + "*" + "\"" + "Operational Metrics~Canadian Dollars (Canadian $/US$)~9999" + "\"";
string replacesfrom = "\"" + "Operational Metrics~Copper C1 Cash Costs (US$/lb) - Lalor~9999" + "\"";
string replacesto = "A10";
string afterreplace = Regex.Replace(mainstr, replacesfrom, replacesto);
```

**Desired output will be.**

```
"A10"*"Operational Metrics~Canadian Dollars (Canadian $/US$)"
```

I tried this logic too but still no luck.

```
public static string ReplaceWholeWord(this string original, string wordToFind, string replacement, RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.None)
        {
            string pattern = String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", wordToFind);
            string ret = Regex.Replace(original, pattern, replacement, regexOptions);
            return ret;
        }
```

with above function i try to replace but unfortunately not being able to replace text **Operational Metrics~Copper C1 Cash Costs (US$/lb) - Lalor** with **A10**

Please suggest what to change in my above code.

Comment: You don't need Regex here because you are simply replacing a static substring; `string.Replace` should suffice. If you must use Regex you need to be aware that parenthesis and the dollar and forward slash characters have special meaning and need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you desperately want to use Regex, continue reading. If not, see [Yaroslav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64819388/9363973)

---

The problems are that you havenescaped Regex special characters, i.E `(`, `)`, `$`, and `/`

Your current Regex is `Operational Metrics~Copper C1 Cash Costs (US$/lb) - Lalor~9999` contains special characters ([Regexr explains them better](https://regexr.com/5g6em)), basically `(` and `)` denote a *capturing group* and `$` denotes the end of your string. Meaning we'll have to escape them with a `\`. That means your Regex (`replacesfrom`) is now

`@"""Operational Metrics~Copper C1 Cash Costs \(US\$\/lb\) - Lalor~9999"""`

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W4iyI6) is a dotnetfiddle showing that it works

Comment: thanks for your fiddle. how can i escape all special character the way you hard code in text that is `string replacesfrom = @"""Operational Metrics~Copper C1 Cash Costs \(US\$\/lb\) - Lalor~9999""";`

Comment: $ should be replace with \$\ ? bracket should be replace with \( & \) ?

Comment: No. Escaping in a Regex is done the same as escaping inside a normal string, just a single `\\` followed by the character you want to escape. I.E `\"` escapes a `"` inside a string, and `\$` escapes the `$` inside the Regex. I just used the verbatim string (`@"..."`) so I don't have to escape the escape (\\) character. I escaped the charactes `(`, `$`, `/`, and `)` separately

Comment: How could i have generic routine which i will call to replace all special character. please suggest a code example or any link which guide me to replace special characters. thanks

Comment: A quick Google search yielded me [`Regex.Escape`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1):

Regex.Replace works differently than String.Replace.
Use

```
string afterreplace = mainstr.Replace(replacesfrom, replacesto);
```

Comment: +1, better than my answer which is unnecessarily using Regex... also, [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EOYcLx)'s a link to a dotnetfiddle showing this works

Comment: Replace may create problem. i need to replace text with in double quote. suppose there could be text like  "Z1"+"Z12" replace will replace Z1 with A10. then output would be "A10"+"A102" this is why i do not use replace function. i need to find out text with in double quote replace. replace function may not work some time & create problem.

Answer (score 0):

first things first, you don't need the "+" in your strings ecxample:

```
string replacesfrom = "\"" + "Operational Metrics~Copper C1 Cash Costs (US$/lb) - Lalor" + "\"";
```

could be:

```
string replacesfrom = "\"Operational Metrics~Copper C1 Cash Costs (US$/lb) - Lalor\"";
```

And what I could understand, this is what you need, to replace:

```
string afterreplace = mainstr.Replace(replacesfrom, replacesto)
```

And to get cell adress, if you don't know how, this should work: [How can i get the Cell address from excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628603/how-can-i-get-the-cell-address-from-excel)