# Convert number to base26 column string for excel. lang perl

Tags: perl, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a column number (eg. 127) into an excel column (eg. AA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa)

How convert number to base26 column string for excel. lang perl

Comment: This is not rent-a-coder.  You should be able to translate these few simple lines.

Answer (score 4):

[`Number::Latin`](http://p3rl.org/Number::Latin)

Answer (score 2):

If it's something quick and dirty, the following sub may be useful.

```
sub column2base26 {

    my $column = shift;
    die "Column $column must be positive" unless $column > 0;

    my $string = 'A';
    $string++ for 2..$column;
    return $string;
}

print column2base26($_), "\n" foreach (23, 15, 333);

# Output:
# W
# O
# LU
```