# C#: Reading values from Excel formulas

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula, closedxml

I've been using **Closed XML** to generate my Excel reports automatically. So far so good, but however I need to save certain formula-generated values back into the database.

The formula would be something like this: `=SUM(Day1, Day2, Day3)`, so simply an Excel formula parser would not fit my bill--I need something that can interact with it!

I don't mind having to save the spreadsheet and then re-opening it. So long as it's fast and efficient, I'm up for anything. Thanks a bunch. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Range("D1").value
```

for getting the value of the formula

Comment: What if, I can only get the cell from a row-col (int, int) reference?

Comment: @matt Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa) for a way to convert your integer column number to an Excel column name (remember to account for your possibly-zero based number).

Comment: IXLWorksheet's Range().Value does not have a get accessor... says the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
if(ws.Cell(i, j).HasFormula) 
       VAL = ws.Cell(i, j).ValueCached
else
       VAL = ws.Cell(i, j).Value.ToString()
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. Please try to elaborate a little as to why this is a correct answer..