# Creating a complex UID thats not a GUID/UUID in the normal sense

Tags: c#, t-sql, uniqueidentifier

I am looking for suggestions to create a incremented ID (much like a license plate number). Instead of the usual 0-9 int32 type counter I am looking for something can go 0-9 then A-Z for each character in the sequence. 
So I would have the potential to have a 6 char ID that would be '2A3DC3' This has the potential to give a much greater depth to the available values.

Comment: Needing to be able to generate a ID that has a lot of dept in a very small space for user use. 36x36x36x36x36x36 gives me more flexibility in a small string than a 10 digit number would. Kind of like a car license plate number.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an auto-incremented `Int32` ID and then format it in a base higher than 10 to get a short string. For example, have a look at [Base36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36#C.23_implementation) has C# code for both encoding and decoding), [Base32](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D%20base32) ([ZBase32](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D%20zbase32) is particularly designed for consumption by humans), or even [Excel column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa).

Comment: This is looking to be the exact direction I am looking; just didn't have the right terminology. I will give it a shot... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code which does it sequentially:

```
var allDigits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var @base = allDigits.Length;
var a = new StringBuilder();
var start = 2176782336;  // minimum 6 digit base36 number
var end = 76187381759;   // maximum 6 digit base36 number

Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
          .Select(n => {
                           int r;
                           var d = n + start;
                           a.Clear();
                           do
                           {
                               r = (int)(d % @base);
                               d = d / @base;
                               a.Insert(0, allDigits[r]);
                           } while(d >= @base);

                           a.Insert(0, allDigits[r]);
                           return a.ToString();
                       })
          .Dump();
```