# how to calculate a value from other fields in excel sheet using formulas

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, xlrd

I'm using `xlrd` package for python to generate my excel reports. 
for some fields, they are a calculations from other fields. 
I'm using

```
worksheet.write(1, 2,  '178', formatting )
worksheet.write(1, 3,  '100', formatting )
```

for the field `(1,4)` is the `SUM of (1,2) and (1,3)`

I can do that if I used : `worksheet.write(1, 4,  '=SUM(A1,B1)', formatting )`

but in my case I'm using numbers `(col, row)` instead of letters `(A1)`.

I tried `chr(1)+':1' - chr(1)+':2'`

but seems like the letters I'm getting don't reflect the numbers.

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated!

The solution I'm using for now is

```
value1 = '178'
value2 = '100'
worksheet.write(1, 2,  value1, formatting )
worksheet.write(1, 3,  value2, formatting )
worksheet.write(1, 4, value1+value2  , formatting )
```

but as you see `I'm not using built in excel formulas` and the excel user won't see where the value came from. like what was the `calculation used?`. exactly for finance department.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple iterative version that should handle arbitrary column numbers, adapted from the C# code at this answer:

[How to convert a column number (eg. 127) into an excel column (eg. AA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa)

```
def column_label(column_number):
    column_labels = []
    column_number = column_number + 1
    while column_number > 0:
        column_number, modulo = divmod(column_number - 1, 26)
        column_labels.append(string.uppercase[modulo])
    return ''.join(reversed(column_labels))
```

This takes a 0-indexed column number, such as those xlrd and xlwt use. I don't love the conversion to 1-indexed before building the names, but I need to think more about the algorithm before replacing it.

Comment: for this I had `import string` because it's not imported when python fired up! just a heads up! :)

Answer (score 1):

`chr(65)=A` in ASCII, so you may need to add 64 to your column. This will of course break if you're going beyond the 26th column.

Comment: I'd use `string.uppercase[col]`, if handling only numbers up to 25. But either should work.

Comment: this is a great solution! but `unfortunately` I'm going beyond 26th columns like `BA`