# In Google Spreadsheet, force value to be relative and increase by one, when copy/paste and select/drag doesn't work

Tags: google-sheets, cell, spreadsheet, formula

When trying to copy/paste and/or select/drag formula `=Indirect("ELA!F"&$A$1)` from one cell to the next in a row, in order to get the variable of column 'F', in the formula, to increase by 1 [i.e. `=Indirect("ELA!F"&$A$1)` to `=Indirect("ELA!G"&$A$1)` to `=Indirect("ELA!H"&$A$1)` etc.]

I cannot seem to get Google Spreadsheet to do this automatically for me, and I do not know how to force Google to change that particular variable/value.

Is there a formula that works the opposite of `$`, thus forcing a value to be relative and increase by 1 instead of forcing it to be absolute?

Answer (score 0):

- Spreadsheets does support relative reference. For relative reference, you'd drop the `$`. But, the part within the quotes won't change. For example, if you had `$A1` and dragged to the next row, it'd change to `$A2`
- If you are looking to get a specific column from another sheet `TRANSPOSE()` would be easier than trying to get a formula to convert the row numbers into a column alphabet.
- And, here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa) on getting the column name from the number. You could do something similar and use `Row()` for the number.