# Obtaining cell name in Aspose Cells

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

I am looking to obtain the name of a cell given a row/column pair. I need a name to use in a formula. For example, I would like to set cell (3, 4) to a formula that adds the values of cells (4, 4) and (5, 4).

Cell (3, 4) is `D5`; (4, 4) is `E5`, and (5, 4) is `F5`. Therefore, my formula should look like this:

```
=E5+F5
```

I can format my formula like this:

```
const int col = 3;
const int row = 4;
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Formula = string.Format(
    "={0}{1}+{2}{3}"
,   (char)('A'+col+1) // <<== Broken, do not use
,   row+1
,   (char)('A'+col+2) // <<== Broken, do not use
,   row+1
);
```

This works fine for columns A..Z, but breaks for columns with names further to the right. I could use [a trick described in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21633017/335858), but the problem looks so basic that it shouldn't require coding on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do this the hard way, because Aspose did it for you. Their `CellsHelper` class has [`CellIndexToName`](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/How+to+get+Cell+Name+from+Row+and+Column+Indices) method, which does exactly what you need:

```
const int col = 3;
const int row = 4;
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Formula =
    $"={CellsHelper.CellIndexToName(row, col+1)}+{CellsHelper.CellIndexToName(row, col+2)}";
```