# Clean algorithm to get Excel column letters from column index

Tags: algorithm

This is trickier than it looks at first blush.

In Excel, columns have letter identifiers:

- 1st column is "A"
- 2nd is "B"
- ...
- 26th is "Z"
- 27th is "AA"
- 28th is "AB"
- ...
- "ZY"
- "ZZ"
- "AAA"
- ...

I am looking for the cleanest algorithm (i.e. the most readable) that can turn the column number into the column identifier.

I explicitely *don't* want a solution that works inside Excel. It needs to run standalone.

I have my solution, but am looking for other approaches.

Here are my (NUnit) test cases. They are correct, to the best of my knowledge.

```
    [TestCase(1, "A")]
    [TestCase(26, "Z")]
    [TestCase(27, "AA")]
    [TestCase(52, "AZ")]
    [TestCase(53, "BA")]
    [TestCase(702, "ZZ")]
    [TestCase(703, "AAA")]
    [TestCase(18278, "ZZZ")]
    [TestCase(18279, "AAAA")]
    [TestCase(475255, "AAAAA")]
```

Comment: `=LEFT(ADDRESS(1, 28, 2), FIND("$", ADDRESS(1, 28, 2))-1)` where 28 is the column.

Comment: @Jeeped OP doesn't want excel solution.

Comment: It was offered as a starting point for whatever language the OP ultimately decides upon.

Comment: Is [this what you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21633017/335858)?

Comment: @MacroMan In any language - just don't slap an Excel built-in function. The test cases use NUnit's syntax, but I recon they're readable enough regardless of used framework

Comment: @pnuts yeah, I just found that question too...

Comment: @pnuts Funny that I didn't see it as a suggestion while writing the question, but it showed up in the list of related questions.