# How to retrieve column names from a sheet?

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating an application to retrieve the column names into listbox from a particular excel sheet and match the column names with the database columns and insert it into the excel data into table

Can you explain how can I can do it?

Already I have retrieved sheet names into the list box

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new ApplicationClass();
 Workbook workBook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"your_file_path");
 Worksheet workSheet = (Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
 Range range = workSheet.UsedRange;
 for (int i = 1; i <= range.Columns.Count; i++)
 {
      ListBox3.Items.Add(((Excel.Range)range.Cells[2, i]).Value2);
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a column number (eg. 127) into an excel column (eg. AA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa)

Answer (score 0):

See [How to convert a- column number eg. 127 into an Excel column eg. AA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182924/1767754) here on Stackoverflow