# How do you preserve OpenXml cell attributes after an edit when Excel saves the document?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to export an excel file with data so that my users can:

- Download an Excel file (export from my program)
- Edit the data in the file
- Save it
- Upload the Excel file (reimport it into my program)

Basically I will give them the experience of having an offline file that they can edit if they do not have any internet access (as ours is a web application)

When creating Excel files using the [OpenXml SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) I use the [OpenXmlElement.SetAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.openxmlelement.setattribute(v=office.14).aspx) method to add attributes to the columns, rows and cells of the worksheet. The attributes I add are used so that on reimport I can match the edited data with the location where it should be stored.

The attributes I export are:

- Database Id's
- Original value (database value at time of export to allow for easy synchronisation on import)
- The date the exported data was last modified

The export routine looks like this for a cell:

```
var cell = new Cell {
   CellReference = string.Format("{0}{1}", Column.Reference, Row.Index),
   DataType = this.CellDataType
};

foreach (var keyValuePair in this.AttributeDictionary) {
   cell.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute {
      LocalName = keyValuePair.Key,
      Value = keyValuePair.Value.ToString()
   });
}
```

This export works fine. When examining the exported file in the [OpenXml Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30425&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True) I can see the attributes are added correctly. When the file is saved after editing in Excel the attributes are not preserved. Is there a way to tell Excel to preserve the attributes or is there another procedure that would be best used here to preserve the data I need for easy re-importation of the data?

Side Question:

What are the attributes for if Excel does not preserve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can force Excel to round trip unknown *attributes* but you can add extension *elements* using [`ExtensionLists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.extensionlist(v=office.14).aspx) and `Extensions`. Excel will roundtrip these elements and are designed (as far as I can make out) for storing application specific data just as you are after.

There doesn't seem to be too much documentation around that I can find but Part 3 of the [ECMA-376 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/flat/publications/Standards/Ecma-376.htm) mentions extensions.

The following code will create a sheet with a value in cell A1 and an `ExtensionList` with one `Extension` in it as a child of that cell:

```
public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath)
{
    if (File.Exists(filepath))
        File.Delete(filepath);

    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
        WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();

        SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);

        // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
        Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

        // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
        {
            Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.
                GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
            SheetId = 1,
            Name = "Sheet1"
        };
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        Row row = new Row()
        {
            RowIndex = 1U
        };

        Cell cell = new Cell()
        {
            CellReference = "A1",
            CellValue = new CellValue("A Test"),
            DataType = CellValues.String
        };

        ExtensionList extensions = new ExtensionList();
        Extension extension = new Extension()
            {
                Uri = "Testing1234"
            };
        extensions.AppendChild(extension);
        extension.AddNamespaceDeclaration("ns", "http://tempuri/someUrl");

        cell.AppendChild(extensions);

        row.Append(cell);

        sheetData.Append(row);

        workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

        // Close the document.
        spreadsheetDocument.Close();
    }
}
```

The following will read the value back again, even if the file has been round tripped through Excel.

```
public static void ReadSheet(string filename, string sheetName)
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, false))
    {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;
        //get the correct sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).First();
        if (sheet != null)
        {
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id) as WorksheetPart;
            foreach (Cell cell in  worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>())
            {
                ExtensionList extensions = cell.GetFirstChild<ExtensionList>();
                if (extensions != null)
                {
                    Extension extension = extensions.GetFirstChild<Extension>();
                    if (extension != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Cell {0} has value {1}", cell.CellReference, extension.Uri);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output from which is

> Cell A1 has value Testing1234

As for your side question:

> What are the attributes for if Excel does not preserve them?

I'm not too sure - the only time I've used the `OpenXmlAttribute` class is when I've used a SAX approach to write a document. In that case you need to write the attributes explicitly along with the elements. For example:

```
List<OpenXmlAttribute> oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();

//cell reference attribute
oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("r", "", "A1"));
//cell type attribute
oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", "", "str"));
//write the start element of a cell with the above attributes
oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), oxa);
//write a value to the cell
oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue("Test"));
//write the end element
oxw.WriteEndElement();
```

My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249343/out-of-memory-exception-using-sqldatareader-and-openxml/25297233#25297233) has a full example of using a SAX approach.

Comment: Works like a charm, I can also add attributes to the extension element and they are preserved as well. Thank you.

Comment: @petelids ExtensionList and Extension can be used for excel but if i want to do the same thing in case of word what should i do? can you please help me out here.