# Given a positive integer, return its corresponding column title as appear in an Excel sheet

Tags: c++, algorithm

Excel Sheet Column Title

Given a positive integer, return its corresponding column title as appear in an Excel sheet.

For example:

```
1 -> A
2 -> B
3 -> C
...
26 -> Z
27 -> AA
28 -> AB
```

My code is here:

```
    class Solution {
public:

 unordered_map<int, char> make_hash(){
    unordered_map<int, char> hash;
    int i;
    char cc;
    for(i = 1, cc = 'A'; i <= 26; i++, cc++)
        hash[i] = cc;

    return hash;
}

string convert_to_title(int n, string & res, unordered_map<int, char> & hash, int counter){

    if(n > 26){
        counter ++;
        convert_to_title(n / 26, res, hash, counter);
    }
    if(n == 26)
        res += "Z";
    if(hash.find(n%26) == hash.end() && n > 26)
        res += hash[n%26+1];
    else
        res += hash[n%26];
    return res;
}



string convertToTitle(int n) {

    unordered_map<int, char> hash = make_hash();
    string res;
    return convert_to_title(n, res, hash, 0);
}
};
```

system pops up with

```
Submission Result: Wrong Answer More Details 

Input:  26
Output: "Z"
Expected:   "Z"
```

REally don't know where is wrong...

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa

Comment: Where are you submitting?

Comment: Can you provide us the link to this problem?

Comment: @PhamTrung https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/excel-sheet-column-title/