# How to get Excel column title?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I try to resolve some task in code wars. I have to create method, which returns column title(occurring in Excel). The method gets one parameter, it's number. For example:

```
def get_column_title(n)
//code
end
```

If n = 1. It should return A.

[image]

[image]

Test cases:

```
Test.assert_equals(get_column_title(1), "A")
Test.assert_equals(get_column_title(26), "Z")
Test.assert_equals(get_column_title(52), "AZ")
Test.assert_equals(get_column_title(53), "BA")
Test.assert_equals(get_column_title(702), "ZZ")
```

What I have:

```
  def number_values
    {
      1 => 'A', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'C', 4 => 'D', 5 => 'E', 6 => 'F', 7 => 'G',
      8 => 'H', 9 => 'I', 10 => 'J', 11 => 'K', 12 => 'L', 13 => 'M', 14 => 'N',
      15 => 'O', 16 => 'P', 17 => 'Q', 18 => 'R', 19 => 'S', 20 => 'T',
      21 => 'U', 22 => 'V', 23 => 'W', 24 => 'X', 25 => 'Y', 26 => 'Z'
    }
  end

def translate_values
    if @n <= 26
      number_values[@n-26*0]
    elsif @n <= 52
        'A'+ number_values[@n-26*1]
    elsif @n <= 78
        'B' + number_values[@n-26*2]
    end
end
```

Issue:
I don't know how to resolve this task algorithmically. I thought about dividing the number by 26 in a loop.
Can you give me some hints how to approach the task?

Source of exercise: 
[codewars.com](https://www.codewars.com/kata/get-the-excel-column-title/)

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/182924/390819

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your number to Base 26 and use `A...Z` instead of `0...25`. The only trick is to subtract one from your number in each step.

Answer (score 1):

```
{alphabetCount=26
alphabetOffset=1

for i in 0 .. 1000
    i = i + alphabetOffset
    category=""

    while i>alphabetCount do
        j=i%alphabetCount

        if j==0 then
            j=alphabetCount
        end

        category=(64+j).chr + category
        i=(i-j)/alphabetCount

        if j==0 then
            i=i-1
         end
    end

    category=(64+i).chr + category + "\n"
    puts category
end}
```

sorry if it is a bit wonky but i am in mobile and could only test via an online compiler :(
but it outputs

```
0=A
...
25=Z
....
702=AAA
```