# Explanation of algorithm that get the excel column title

Tags: excel, algorithm

According to this topic:
[How to convert a column number (e.g. 127) into an excel column (e.g. AA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa)

I don't understand what is in algorithm:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182924/4645227)

Could someone explain me, what is happening in a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, in effect, "converting" the column number to base 26, where the "digits" are the letters A..Z.

For example, for column 720:

- `modulo` = (720-1)%26 = 17
- `columnName` = 'R'
- `dividend` = (720-17)/26 = 27
- `modulo` = (27-1)%26 = 0
- `columnName` = `A`+`columnName` = `AR`
- `dividend` = (27-0)/26 = 1
- `modulo` = (1-1)%26 = 0
- `columnName` = `A` + `columnName` = `AAR`
- `dividend` = (1-0)/26 = 0

Resulting in `AAR`.

Comment: Ok, but why we subtract one from a number in modulo?

Comment: To account for the first column being 1.

Comment: I don't understand... When we have e.g. 720, and we subtract 1, the result is 719 and what this gives us? Why don't we do 720 % 26?

Comment: Column 1 should map to A; if you don't subtract 1, it would map to B.

Comment: I still don't understand :( Why should map to A and how you see that subtract one map to A?