# Is there a built-in way to convert a column number to an Excel column with Laravel Excel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-excel

I want to add some style on a column using Laravel Excel. I know this column is the (let's say) 42nd, but I don't know the Excel code (like `AA`, `BC`, etc.).

I know I can build a function (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa)) to convert the column number to a letter, but I not sure it's the right way.

Is there a built-in way to convert a column number to an Excel column with Laravel Excel?

Comment: You want to export full table or some columns ? I have used laravel excel but i did't find any such inbuilt function. but I have develop my own function for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method in `PHPExcel` and i guess Laravel Excel uses that library.

You can do like this:

```
\PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex(1);
```

This will return, `B`

Comment: Thanks! BTW, It will return 'B' (doc says: "Column index (base 0 !!!)")

Answer (score 5):

Since [version 3.1](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/) of Laravel Excel is based off of the newest PHP Excel which uses the latest PhpSpreadsheet classes, the helper functions to manipulate coordinates have been moved to a new dedicated class. Search for "Dedicated class to manipulate coordinates" [on this page](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/migration-from-PHPExcel/).

Therefore, you can do this moving forward:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
...
Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex(1);
```