# How can I get this PivotTable to display the values I want it to, in the location I want them to be?

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, excel-interop

After much gnashing of teeth, &c, I was able to achieve a modicum of success with generating a PivotTable. It now sports both a "row filter" (on the Descriptions) and a "column filter" (on the "month year" columns), like so:

[image]

This is accomplished with the following code:

```
var pch = _xlBook.PivotCaches();
Range sourceData = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].Range["A1:G318"]; // TODO: Make range dynamic

PivotCache pc = pch.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, sourceData);
PivotTable pvt = pc.CreatePivotTable(_xlPivotTableSheet.Range["A8"], "PivotTable");

pvt.PivotFields("Description").Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
pvt.PivotFields("MonthYr").Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
```

The source data ("PivotData") looks like this:

[image]

What the PivotTable *should* look like, when all is said and coded, is this:

[image]

What do I need to do to achieve this look (this data, and in these locations)? I reckon part of it is has to do with the assignments of more XlPivotFieldOrientation values to more PivotFields, but don't know just what they should be.

And first but possibly least (but still important), "Row Labels" should say "Description" and "Column Labels" should say "Month"

### UPDATE

I am trying to add, piece by piece, the code needed to make the various columns display. I tried this:

pvt.AddDataField(pvt.PivotFields("TotalQty"), "Total Packages", XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum).NumberFormat = "###,##0";

...hoping that the data from the source data's "TotalQty" column would display in a column headed "Total Packages"

It does indeed display, but the label "Total Packages", appears in an odd/out-of-the-way place:

[image]

How can I get the "Total Packages" label to display where it does in the "model" screenshot?

### UPDATE 2

Hambone mentioned my TODO in his answer; I got back to it and made that dynamic this way:

```
int rowsUsed = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].UsedRange.Rows.Count;
int colsUsed = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].UsedRange.Columns.Count;
string colsUsedAsAlpha = GetExcelColumnName(colsUsed);
string endRange = string.Format("{0}{1}", colsUsedAsAlpha, rowsUsed);
Range sourceData = _xlBook.Worksheets["PivotData"].Range[string.Format("A1:{0}",
  endRange)];

// Pass "1", get "A", etc.; from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-  
to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa
public static string GetExcelColumnName(int columnNumber)
{
    int dividend = columnNumber;
    string columnName = String.Empty;
    while (dividend > 0)
    {
        var modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
        columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
        dividend = (dividend - modulo) / 26;
    }
    return columnName;
}
```

BTW, I can't find my bronze badges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things...  you didn't ask this specifically, but in your code you had a "TODO" as making the range dynamic.  A really nice way to do this is to convert your range to a table.  Once you do this, you can pass the table instead of the range.  The table, as you probably know from previous posts would be:

```
ListObject tab = _xlPivotTableSheet.ListObjects["Table1"];
PivotCache pc = pch.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, tab);
```

If you do this, boundaries don't matter -- the table goes all as one data source.

Back to your issue at hand.  You added your data fields okay:

```
pvt.AddDataField(pvt.PivotFields("TotalQty"), "Total Packages",
    XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum);
pvt.AddDataField(pvt.PivotFields("TotalSales"), "Total Purchases",
     XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum);
```

The calculated field is a bit more tricky.  I didn't quite understand the calculation for "% of total," but for illustration purposes this is how you would do average price:

```
PivotField avg = pvt.CalculatedFields().Add("Average Price", "=TotalSales/TotalQty", true);
avg.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
```

And you're right -- the orientation is not what you expect.  This setting is done at the pivot table level -- it's either rows or columns.  To get the view you're looking for you would change it from the default columns to rows:

```
pvt.DataPivotField.Orientation = XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
```

Once you do this, I think the pivot table will look more the way you expect.

Comment: With the first bit of code, would that change my existing code:
PivotCache pc = pch.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, sourceData);
to:
PivotCache pc = pch.Create(XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, tab);
?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Tables (ListObjects) are a real game-changer.  I absolutely love them.