# Repeating letters like excel columns?

Tags: python, excel, string, modulus

I want to create a list of string that resemble the column letters in Microsoft Excel. For example, after 26 columns, the next columns become `AA`, `AB`, `AC`, etc.

I have tried using the modulus operator, but I just end up with `AA`, `BB`, `CC`, etc...

```
import string

passes_through_alphabet = 0

for num, col in enumerate([_ for _ in range(40)]):
    if num % 26 == 0:
        passes_through_alphabet += 1
    excel_col = string.ascii_uppercase[num%26] * passes_through_alphabet
    print(num, excel_col)

0 A
1 B
2 C
3 D
...
22 W
23 X
24 Y
25 Z
26 AA
27 BB
28 CC
...
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this:

```py
import string
import itertools
list(itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=2))
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ...
```

Combining this with the first set of letters, and joining the pairs results in:

```py
list(
    itertools.chain(
        string.ascii_uppercase, 
        (''.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=2))
))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', .. 'AA', 'AB', 'AC' .. 'ZZ']
```

To generalize, we define a generator that builds up bigger and bigger products. Note that the yield is only available in python 3.3+, but you can just use a for loop to yield each item if you're on python 2.

```
def excel_cols():
    n = 1
    while True:
        yield from (''.join(group) for group in itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=n))
        n += 1
```

```
list(itertools.islice(excel_cols(), 28))
```

output

```
['A', 'B', 'C', ... 'X', 'Y', 'Z','AA', 'AB']
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/182009/6591347

```
def num_to_excel_col(n):
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError("Number must be positive")
    result = ""
    while True:
        if n > 26:
            n, r = divmod(n - 1, 26)
            result = chr(r + ord('A')) + result
        else:
            return chr(n + ord('A') - 1) + result
```

Answer (score 3):

This generator function will work with arbitrary alphabets:

```
import string

def labels(alphabet=string.ascii_uppercase):
    assert len(alphabet) == len(set(alphabet))  # make sure every letter is unique
    s = [alphabet[0]]
    while 1:
        yield ''.join(s)
        l = len(s)
        for i in range(l-1, -1, -1):
            if s[i] != alphabet[-1]:
                s[i] = alphabet[alphabet.index(s[i])+1]
                s[i+1:] = [alphabet[0]] * (l-i-1)
                break
        else:
            s = [alphabet[0]] * (l+1)

> x = labels(alphabet='ABC')
> print([next(x) for _ in range(20)])
['A', 'B', 'C', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC', 'AAA', 'AAB', ... ]
```

It generates the next string from the current one:

1. Find the first character from the back that is not the last in the alphabet: e.g. `!= 'Z'`

   b) increment it: set it to the next alphabet letter

   c) reset all following characters to the first alphabet character
2. if no such incrementable character was found, start over with all first alphabet letters, increasing the length by `1`

One can write a more readable/comprehensive function at the cost of a (much) larger memory footprint, especially if many labels are generated:

```
def labels(alphabet=string.ascii_uppercase):
    agenda = deque(alphabet)
    while agenda:
        s = agenda.popleft()
        yield s
        agenda.append([s+c for c in alphabet])
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
itertools.chain(*[itertools.product(map(chr, range(65,91)), repeat=i) for i in xrange(1, 10)])
```

Please notice to the magic number 10 - this is the maximum letters in column name.

**Explain:**
First creating the A-Z letters as list:

```
map(chr, range(65,91))
```

then using product for creating the combinations (length starts from 1 and ends at 10)

```
itertools.product(map(chr, range(65,91)), repeat=i)
```

And finally concat all those generators into single generator using `itertools.chain`

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be easier

```
cols = [chr(x) for x in range(65, 91)] + \
       [chr(x) + chr(y) for x in range(65, 91) for y in range(65, 91)] + \
       [chr(x) + chr(y) + chr(z) for x in range(65, 91) for y in range(65, 91) for z in range(65, 91)]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).