# Find Excel/CSV File's Actual Column References- Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Let say I have an excel sheet like this,

[image]

If I read this file in pandas, I can get `Column1`, `Column2`, `Column3` as headers.

However, I want to know/create an output possibly a dictionary that is like this,

```
{Column1: 'A', Column2: 'B', Column3: 'C'}
```

The reason is I have another dictionary from master mapping file (that already had the references for each column done manually) that has all the references to each `Column` like this,

```
{Column1: 'A', Column2: 'B', Column3: 'C', Column4: 'D'}
```

This way, I can cross check keys and values and then if there is any mismatch, I can identify those mismatches. How can I get the original column name such as `A` for `Column1` etc.. while reading a file into pandas?? Any ideas??

Comment: There is `usecols` in this `pandas` [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) But does not help much in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict` with `zip` to map column names to letters. Assumes you have a maximum of 26 columns.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3),
                  columns=['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'])

d = dict(zip(df.columns, ascii_uppercase))

print(d)

{'Column1': 'A', 'Column2': 'B', 'Column3': 'C'}
```

For more than 26 columns, you can adapt the `itertools.product` solution available in [Repeating letters like excel columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176498/repeating-letters-like-excel-columns)

Comment: Nice way to think about this. I had no idea `ascii_uppecase` existed!

Comment: I was reading `ascii_uppercase`, my understanding is I am stuck at 26 columns for now unless, there is a way to concatenate `ascii_uppercase` characters to go more than 26 columns. i.e. In excel, after `Z`, it is `AA`, `AB` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Panadas rename method to replace the dataframe column names using your existing mapping dictionary:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': [1, 2], 'Column2': [3, 4], 'Column3': [5, 6]})

existing_mapping = {'Column1': 'A', 'Column2': 'B', 'Column3': 'C', 'Column4': 'D'}

df = df.rename(columns=existing_mapping)
```

Comment: this will not help for direct comparing though!