# Load a apreadsheet and copy a row and pasted it in a different location

Tags: python, openpyxl

How can I copy a row for example from D51 to F51 and paste these values in the row T20 to AF20.

I know how to load a spreadsheet

```
workbook = load_workbook(output)
sheet = workbook.active
```

But I dont know how to itenarate in a loop to get this

```
    sheet["T2"] = "=D6"
    sheet["U2"] = "=E6"
    sheet["V2"] = "=F6"
    sheet["W2"] = "=G6"
    sheet["X2"] = "=H6"
    sheet["Y2"] = "=I6"
    sheet["Z2"] = "=J6"
    sheet["AA2"] = "=K6"
    sheet["AB2"] = "=L6"
    sheet["AC2"] = "=M6"
    sheet["AD2"] = "=N6"
    sheet["AE2"] = "=O6"
    sheet["AF2"] = "=P6"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using code below...
Note that the file `output.xlsx` is opened, updated and saved. The function `num_to_excel_col` is borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176498/repeating-letters-like-excel-columns).
This will update columns 20 (T) onwards for the next 15 columns (all row 2) with the text as  "=D6", "=E6", etc. The num_to_col function will convert the col number to equivalent excel string (for eg. 27 will be converted to AA, etc.)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx')
ws = workbook.active

def num_to_excel_col(n):
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError("Number must be positive")
    result = ""
    while True:
        if n > 26:
            n, r = divmod(n - 1, 26)
            result = chr(r + ord('A')) + result
        else:
            return chr(n + ord('A') - 1) + result

outcol = 4 #Paste in col 'D'

for col in range(20,35): #col 20 is T and doing this for next 15 columns
    txt = "="+num_to_excel_col(outcol)+"6"
    print(txt)
    ws.cell(row=2, column=col).value = txt
    outcol += 1

workbook.save("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for my next question. How can I make it works if instead of the locations asked in the question, I would want to know for example sheet["T3"] = "=D11 ... sheet["AF3"] = "=P11"" I am trying to create a function to reuse your code (that worked) many occasion

Comment: From what was in the original question to now - you are changing the row number, is that correct? In that case, assuming you are getting that inputs as integers, then replace the ````"6"```` by ````str(out_row)```` and similarly replace the ````row=2````, by ````row=input_row````

Comment: openpyxl already includes such conversion functions.