# Rotate text only in specific Excel row

Tags: c#, excel, rotation, office-interop

I'd like to rotate headers in an Excel file using `Microsoft.Office.Interop`. To achieve this, I'm using the following code:

```
worksheet.Range["A1:" + worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count + "1"].Style.Orientation
    = Excel.XlOrientation.xlUpwards;
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Rotated cells]

As you can see, **every** cell gets rotated although I'm only specifying the first row. However, I just want the headers to be rotated:

[image: Rotated headers]

I even tried it with a `for` loop for every column:

```
for (int counter = 1; counter <= worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; counter++)
    worksheet.Range[GetExcelColumnName(counter) + "1"].Style.Orientation
        = Excel.XlOrientation.xlUpwards;
```

But I get the same result. What should I do to only change the orientation of the headers?

([Method `GetExcelColumnName`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just convert the entire row 1.

```
worksheet.Range["1:1"].Style.Orientation = Excel.XlOrientation.xlUpwards;
worksheet.Rows["1"].Style.Orientation = Excel.XlOrientation.xlUpwards;
```

fwiw, in VBA this might be best handled with application.intersect of rows(1) and the .usedrange. From your code it looks like that would be,

```
Excel.Intersect(worksheet.Range["1:1"], worksheet.UsedRange).Style.Orientation = Excel.XlOrientation.xlUpwards;
/* just the cells, not the style */
Excel.Intersect(worksheet.Range["1:1"], worksheet.UsedRange).Cells.Orientation = Excel.XlOrientation.xlUpwards;
```

Comment: Nice idea, but still all rows are rotated :(

Comment: It sounds like you have a linked style and you are resetting the properties of the entire style. Can you *just* reset the orientation of the cells without changing the style or can you apply a different style to the non-headers?

Comment: There is a [Style.Orientation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839229.aspx) property and a [Range.Orientation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198186.aspx) property; you need the latter.

Comment: Your edit worked ("just the cells, not the style"). I changed the code to `worksheet.Rows["1"].Cells.Orientation`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was:

```
ws.SelectedRange[1, 1, 1, 15].Style.TextRotation = 180;
```

TextRotation for vertical text: 90 or 180 (upwards, downwards)