# Max column ref in Excel (xlsx)

Tags: excel, openxml, spreadsheet

Does anyone know what the maximum alphabetic value of a column reference in MS Excel is (open xml format onwards)?

All attempts to search the web for this, just bring up maximum values that can go in the cells themselves, so I thought I'd try SO. This question must have been asked before, but I couldn't see an existing similar question, so apologies if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer ("XFD") buried in answers way down the list on different question...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14780053/6002505

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29550239/6002505

The max numerical value is 16384 which should be "XFD" according to the answers above.

Comment: It depends on version though. Excel 2007 and higher it will be 16384. However Excel 2003 and lower had 256.