# How can I convert an integer to A1 notation?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api, notation

I am trying to create a method that will find the next column after a given column. For example:

```
input: A
output: B
```

It seems quite simple at first. I was just going to use the following method:

```
public static char nextLetter(char c) {
    c++;
    return c;
}
```

The problem arises when you get past column Z. In Google Sheets, after column Z, column names are two letters, then three, etc. So after column `Z` comes `AA`, after `AZ` comes `BA`, after `ZZ` comes `AAA`, etc. My next thought was to first figure out the column position in terms of index. So column `AA` would 27, `BA` 52, etc.

Finding the index of the column is not the problem I'm facing right now. I need to figure out how to convert that index to the corresponding column name. I was going to try the following method, but I realized that it is also limited to A-Z:

```
public static char getLetter(int index) {
    return (char) (index + 64);
}
```

At this point, I am thinking that a recursive method is needed. However, I cannot figure out to set it up. This is as far as I got:

```
private static void getNotation(int size) {
    int divided = size / 26;
    int remainder = size % 26;

    String notation = "";

    while (divided % 26 > 0) {
        // Here is where the need for a recursive method comes in
    }

}
```

Does anyone know a good way to convert an integer (index) to the corresponding column name?

### EDIT

I just found a very helpful resource on Github which deals with hexavigesimals: https://gist.github.com/pinguet62/9817978

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getNextColumn("A"));
        System.out.println(getNextColumn("Z"));
        System.out.println(getNextColumn("AA"));
        System.out.println(getNextColumn("AZ"));
        System.out.println(getNextColumn("ZA"));
        System.out.println(getNextColumn("ZZ"));
        System.out.println(getNextColumn("AAA"));
        System.out.println(getNextColumn("ABA"));
        System.out.println(getNextColumn("ABZ"));
        System.out.println(getNextColumn("ZZZ"));
    }

    static String getNextColumn(String column) {
        column = column.toUpperCase();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean allZ = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < column.length(); i++) {
            if (!(column.charAt(i) == 'Z')) {
                allZ = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (allZ) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= column.length(); i++) {
                sb.append('A');
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
        boolean charAfterZ = false;
        int indexOfZ = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < column.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (column.charAt(i) == 'Z') {
                charAfterZ = true;
                indexOfZ = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (charAfterZ) {
            sb.append(column.substring(0, indexOfZ + 1) + (char) (column.charAt(indexOfZ + 1) + 1));
            if (column.length() > indexOfZ + 2) {
                sb.append(column.substring(indexOfZ + 1));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        char lastChar = column.charAt(column.length() - 1);

        if (lastChar == 'Z') {
            sb.append(column.substring(0, column.length() - 2) + (char) (column.charAt(column.length() - 2) + 1) + ""
                    + 'A');
        } else {
            if (column.length() > 1) {
                sb.append(column.substring(0, column.length() - 1) + ""
                        + (char) (column.charAt(column.length() - 1) + 1));
            } else {
                sb.append((char) (column.charAt(column.length() - 1) + 1));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
B
AA
AB
BA
ZB
AAA
AAB
ABB
ACA
AAAA
```

Comment: I like this answer because it saves me the trouble of getting the column index. +1

Answer (score 9):

I created an example:

```
class Test {
    static char[] alphabet = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
                               'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
                               'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

    private static String indexToColumnName(int i) {
        if (i >= alphabet.length) {
            return indexToColumnName((int)Math.floor(i / alphabet.length) - 1)
              + indexToColumnName(i % alphabet.length);
        }
        return Character.toString(alphabet[i]);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 800; ++i) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + indexToColumnName(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The above will yield something like:

```
0: A
1: B
2: C
3: D
...
24: Y
25: Z
26: AA
27: AB
...
700: ZY
701: ZZ
702: AAA
703: AAB
...
```

In this case, it's zero-index, but that you could easily change yourself.

Comment: This works beautifully! If you have the time to explain what exactly you are doing in your answer, I think that would improve it's long-term value. Nevertheless, I like this answer. It's neat and clean and it works. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
private static String getNotation(int size) {
        String result = "";
        int q = 0; // How many characters does the notation consist of?
        int f1 = 0;
        int f2 = 0;
        while (f2 < size) {
            q += 1;
            f1 = f2;
            f2 += Math.pow(26, q);
        }

        size -= f1;
        size--;
        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            result = (char) (size % 26 + 65) + result;
            size /= 26;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works works nicely. If you have the time to explain what exactly you are doing in your answer, I think that would improve it's long-term value. I am especially curious what you are doing with your `q` variable... I wish it was possible to accept two answers, but alas, it is not. +1

Answer (score 1):

I suppose like hexa (base 16), you can work with a base 26. May be try to use a base 10 to base X converter.
The main problem is that in this case after "number" "Z" you have number "AA" like if after number 9 you will have 00. Or in hexa if after F you have 00 instead of 10.

I tried a lot by myself but finally found this topic :
[How to convert a column number (eg. 127) into an excel column (eg. AA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa)

In Java :

```
private static String getNotation(int size) {
    str = "";
    int r;
    while(size >0) {
        r = (size-1) % 26;
        str = getLetter(r+1)+ str;
        size = (size-r) /26 ;
    }
    return str;
}
```

It's seem the solution is just the -1 near the modulo, if you remove it you will have A considered as 0 and so after Z there will be BA like a decimal to base 26 convertor.

Comment: That is really smart! You are right! This is a lot like a base 26 number system. You also provided a working example. +1

Answer (score 1):

yesterday I needed to convert an integer to A1 notation in Go, so I made [this](https://gist.github.com/martincapello/074146e5317e1ff85080f2967dc58f4b) recursive function (ported to java to match question tags):

```java
  public static String indexToA1Notation(int column) {
    if (column <= 'Z' - 'A') {
      return Character.toString('A' + column);       
    }
    return String.format("%s%s", indexToA1Notation((column/26)-1), Character.toString('A'+column%26));
  }
```