# How to increment alphanumeric number in python?

Tags: python, auto-increment, alphanumeric

I am creating a passkey of 16 alphanumeric characters where I am generating starting 4 digits with A001, A002, A003 till A999. Once it goes till A999, the alphabet will auto increase to B and digits will again start with 001. And the same process will go till Z999. Once the A-Z series will over, then it will start with AA01 and so on. How to do this thing in python? As I am new in python so I tried it on my own and also tried some examples but I am unable to make the increment of characters.
Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

```
rec=0
new_list16 = []
def autoIncrement():
    global rec
    first = 'A'
    i = chr(ord(first))
    new_list16.append(i)

    while True:
        pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
        pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
        if (rec == 0):
            rec += pStart
        else:
            rec = rec + pInterval
        return str(rec).zfill(3)
#print(autoIncrement())
new_list16.append(autoIncrement())

print(*new_list16, sep = '')
```

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa) for the A-Z part; the 001 part is just the number modulo 1000.

Comment: Going from A999 to B001 instead of B000 really messes things up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going from `A999` to `B001` instead of `B000` really messes things up a bit, but you can still use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182924/1639625) for the A-Z part, and a simple modulo operation for the numbers.

```
def excel_format(num):
    # see https://stackoverflow.com/a/182924/1639625
    res = ""
    while num:
        mod = (num - 1) % 26
        res = chr(65 + mod) + res
        num = (num - mod) // 26
    return res

def full_format(num, d=3):
    chars = num // (10**d-1) + 1 # this becomes   A..ZZZ
    digit = num %  (10**d-1) + 1 # this becomes 001..999
    return excel_format(chars) + "{:0{}d}".format(digit, d)

for i in range(10000):
    print(i, full_format(i, d=2))
```

Number of digits in the numeric part is controlled with the optional `d` parameter. I'll use `2` for purpose of demonstration, but `3` works just as well.

```
0 A01
...
98 A99
99 B01
...
2573 Z99
2574 AA01
...
9998 CW99
9999 CX01
```

Comment: It completely works fine till Z999, after this, it will print 5 digits of number, whereas I only want 4 digits of number.

Comment: The next number after Z999 should be AA01. Not AA001

Comment: @rajatmaan Ah, thought that was a typo. That makes it all quite a bit more complicated. Also, what happens after ZZZZ9, does it go on with ZZZZA, and then end at ZZZZZ?

Comment: please review the answer which I uploaded today. Its all in 4 digit till ZZ99.

Answer (score 1):

This probably needs to be tested and refactored more, but here's a start for you:

```
def leadingZeros(number, digits):
    numberString = str(number)
    for digit in range(1, digits):
        if number < 10**digit:
            numberString = '0' + numberString
    return numberString


def autoIncrement(oldNumber):
    order = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!'
    lastDigitOrder = order.find(oldNumber[3])
    newNumber = ''
    if order.find(oldNumber[1]) <= 9:
        # 3 digit number
        number = int(oldNumber[1:]) + 1
        letter = oldNumber[0]
        if 1000 == number:
            letterOrder = order.find(oldNumber[0])
            letter = order[letterOrder + 1]
        newNumber = letter + leadingZeros(number % 1000, 3)
    elif order.find(oldNumber[2]) <= 9:
        # 2 digit number
        number = int(oldNumber[2:]) + 1
        letters = oldNumber[0:2]
        if 100 == number:
            letterOrder = order.find(oldNumber[1])
            letter = order[letterOrder + 1]
            letters = oldNumber[0] + letter
        newNumber = letters + leadingZeros(number % 100, 2)
    elif order.find(oldNumber[3]) <= 9:
        # 1 digit number
        number = int(oldNumber[3]) + 1
        letters = oldNumber[0:3]
        if 10 == number:
            letterOrder = order.find(oldNumber[2])
            letter = order[letterOrder + 1]
            letters = oldNumber[0:2] + letter
        newNumber = letters + leadingZeros(number % 10, 1)
    else:
        # just letters
        print(oldNumber)
        letterOrder = order.find(oldNumber[3])
        letter = order[letterOrder + 1]
        newNumber = oldNumber[0:3] + letter

    # if one of the digits has gone past Z then we need to update the letters
    if '!' == newNumber[3]:
        # past Z in 4th digit
        letterOrder = order.find(oldNumber[2])
        newNumber = newNumber[0:2] + order[letterOrder + 1] + 'A'
    if '!' == newNumber[2]:
        # past Z in 3rd digit
        letterOrder = order.find(oldNumber[1])
        newNumber = newNumber[0:1] + order[letterOrder + 1] + 'A' + newNumber[3]
    if '!' == newNumber[1]:
        # past Z in 2nd digit
        letterOrder = order.find(oldNumber[0])
        newNumber = order[letterOrder + 1] + 'A' + newNumber[2:]

    return newNumber


print(autoIncrement('A999'))
print(autoIncrement('AA99'))
print(autoIncrement('AAA9'))
print(autoIncrement('AAAA'))
print(autoIncrement('AZZ9'))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite what you are asking for, but if your requirement is for 4-character "sequential" strings, let me suggest a far more simpler approach. Why not simply used base 36 numbers? That is, have your numbers go from `0, 1, 2, ... A, B, C, ... Z, 10, 11, 12, ... 1Z, ...` Then to convert one of the base 36 strings to an int it is simply:

```
n = int('12AV', 36)
```

And to convert an int to a base n string:

```
def baseN(num, base, numerals="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"):
      return ((num == 0) and numerals[0]) or (baseN(num // base, base, numerals).lstrip(numerals[0]) + numerals[num % base])
```

Putting it all together:

```
n = int('12AV', 36)
s = baseN(n + 1, 36)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
12AW
```

You can, of course, start with 'A001' if you need to. You will then go to `A00Z` after 35 iterations. You will end up generating the same numbers as in your original method, just in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

```
def auto_increment(number):
    if number == 'ZZZZ':
        return 'ZZZZ'

    digits = "".join([i for i in number if i.isdigit()])
    chars = "".join([i for i in number if not i.isdigit()])
    if int(digits) == int('9' * len(digits)):
        digits = "000"
        new_char = [ord(i) for i in chars]
        if new_char[-1] % ord('Z') == 0:
            new_char = "".join([chr(i) for i in new_char]) + 'A'
        else:
            new_char[-1] = new_char[-1] + 1
            new_char = "".join([chr(i) for i in new_char])
    else:
        new_char = chars

    new_digit = int(digits) + 1
    l = len(new_char) 
    ll = len(str(new_digit))
    new_digit = (("0" * (3-ll)) + str(new_digit))[(l-1):]
    return f"{new_char}{new_digit}"
```

This function return you the next number, given any number. 
for example: A999 will return AB01.

you can now just use this function in a loop.

Comment: Sir, it also works fine.But the  problem is that after Z999, the digits should remain same, but it varies to 5 digits.

Comment: And could i do it with using functions because this passkey work is included in a running function.?

Comment: after Z999, it should go to ZA01 because we are using letters after digits.and it is working perfectly. It never goes to 5 digits, have you even tried running it? Also can you also select it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the solutions you had provided. But I tried something exactly which I want for my question. Please check it and give your comments on it.

```
def full_format(i):
    # limit of first range is 26 letters (A-Z) times 999 numbers (001-999)
    if i < 26 * 999:
        c,n = divmod(i,999)   # quotient c is index of letter 0-25, remainder n is 0-998
        c = chr(ord('A') + c) # compute letter
        n += 1
        return f'{c}{n:03}'
    # After first range, second range is 26 letters times 26 letters * 99 numbers (01-99)
    elif i < 26*999 + 26*26*99:
        i -= 26*999               # remove first range offset
        cc,n = divmod(i,99)       # remainder n is 0-98, use quotient cc to compute two letters
        c1,c2 = divmod(cc,26)     # c1 is index of first letter, c2 is index of second letter
        c1 = chr(ord('A') + c1)   # compute first letter
        c2 = chr(ord('A') + c2)   # compute second letter
        n += 1
        return f'{c1}{c2}{n:02}'
    else:
        raise OverflowError(f'limit is {26*999+26*26*99}')

for i in range(92880, 92898):
    print(full_format(i))
```