# How to make an list if i have to start with A end according to length of data generate list containing [A,B,C...,AA]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, ascii

Get stuck at one point.

I have one list containing n elements so according to length,
I have to generate list.

For example i have an list contains 25 element then new list will be [A,B,C,...,Y] and for example list contains 26 elements then [A,B,C,...,Z].

Up to z i can easily get list but now i am getting more than 26 elements.
for example length is 27 then i want these type of list [A,B,C,...,Y,Z,AA].

so, how i am able to get these type of list any suggestion ???

Comment: Can you add your current code plus anything you've tried. This will help others understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can something like BA ever appear in the list?

Comment: Check out how excel column names are generated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-e-g-127-into-an-excel-column-e-g-aa

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/182733/base-26-letters-and-base-10-using-recursion here you can find theory and code

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem yes if length of list is more than 52

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to write this with `itertools`: `itr` generates an infinite number of combinations, first of length 1, then of length 2, etc. Using `islice` takes the required number of elements.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
from itertools import product, count, islice

itr = ("".join(tup) 
  # choose number of letters, e.g. 1, 2, 3 
  for k in count(1)
  # choose all tuples of k letters, e.g. (A, ), (B, ), ... (A, A,) ...
  for tup in product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=k))

res = list(islice(itr, 28))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
import string
def letters_list_generator(number):
    alphabet_string = string.ascii_uppercase
    alphabet_list = list(alphabet_string)
    letter_list = []
    for i in range(0,number):
        multiplier = int(i/26)+1
        letter_index = i%26
        string_for_list = alphabet_list[letter_index] * multiplier
        letter_list.append(string_for_list)
    return letter_list
```

Comment: hey i see your code but after AA i want list like AB,AC,,,AZ,BA...BZ.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can try this code:

```
list_1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list_2 = ['1', '2', '3']
list_3 = []
for i in range(3):
    list_3.append(list_1[i] + list_2[i]
```

The result is `sum = ['A1', 'B2', 'C3']`. If you play with the for loop, you can obtain what you want.

Comment: Sorry brother these is not output i want.