# I want to Generate Array From 'A' to 'ZZ' In Angular & C#. How it can be possible?

Tags: c#, arrays, angular

I am working on project where User have to insert character between A to AZ.
Ex.
If User Enter Values Like This

> - Field 1= **AA**
> - Field 2= **AD**
> - Then I have to generate **AA,AB,AC,AD**.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-e-g-127-into-an-excel-column-e-g-aa

Comment: I do not think  that. both are different, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string start = "AD", end = "BC";

int p1 = int.Parse(string.Join("", start.Select(c => (int)c)));
int p2 = int.Parse(string.Join("", end.Select(c => (int)c)));
var range = Enumerable.Range('A', 26);
var combo = range.Select(c => ((char)c).ToString()).ToList();
combo.AddRange(
from r in range from r2 in range select string.Concat((char)r, (char)r2));
var results = combo.Where(l =>
{
    var v = int.Parse(string.Join("", l.Select(c => (int)c)));
    return v >= p1 && v <= p2;
});

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", results));
```

Output: `AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU,AV,AW,AX,AY,AZ,BA,BB,BC`

Explanation:

Take the numeric value of each character in a pair and string concatenate them, e.g.

```
"AD" = "65" + "68" = 6568 (lower bound)
"BC" = "66" + "67" = 6667 (upper bound)
```

From a list of generated pairs AA to ZZ, compare the numeric value using the same formula above to get the desired result

```
"AA" = "65" + "65" = 6565 (outside bound)
"AB" = "65" + "65" = 6566 (outside bound)
...
"AD" = "65" + "68" = 6568 (inside bound)
...
"BD" = "66" + "68" = 6668 (outside bound)
```

Comment: Is this working on C#?

Comment: Yes it's for C#

Comment: What if I need to Generate Array From A To BB With this solution?

Comment: sure, i've updated the solution. now you can generate e.g. B to H or A to ZZ

Answer (score 1):

Finally issue is solved.
Sharing my answer For Angular Code. Hope it will help others too.

Function to Convert Number To Char

```
   numberToCol(num) {
     var str = '', q, r;
     while (num > 0) {
       q = (num - 1) / 26;
       r = (num - 1) % 26
       num = Math.floor(q)
       str = String.fromCharCode(65 + r) + str;
     }
     return str;
   }
```

Function To Convert Char To Number

```
 GenerateAlphabeticArray(letter1, letter2) {
 
     let var1 = letter1.split('').reduce((r, a) => r * 26 + parseInt(a, 36) - 9, 0);
     let var2 = letter2.split('').reduce((r, a) => r * 26 + parseInt(a, 36) - 9, 0);
 
     let a = [];
 
     for (let i = var1; i <= var2; i++) {
       a.push(this.numberToCol(i))
     }
     console.log("AtoZData = ", a);
     return a;
   }
```

Make a call of fuction

```
this.GenerateAlphabeticArray('AA', 'AD');
```

Output

```
['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD']
```

Comment: [You are welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79DijItQXMM) ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested loop should do it. Something like:

```
var alphabets = new List<string>();
for(int i = 65;i< 65+26;i++)
    for(int j = 65;j< 65+26;j++)
        alphabets.Add($"{(char)i}{(char)j}");
```

Comment: this solution is work but it generate array From AA to AZ.
I want to generate array according to user requirement.
if User Enter From AA TO QA, Then I have to generate array from AA to QA.

Comment: Can you update the question to show examples of these user requirements? How are you passing in those requirements to your generator method?

Comment: Have a look now. I have updated question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work to get the values you are expecting

```
public static void combination() {
            string[] letters = { "a", "b", "c", "d"... };
        List<string> combinations = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < letters.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j<letters.Length; j++)
                {
                    combinations.Add(letters[i]+letters[j]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I want to generate array according to user requirement. if User Enter From AA TO QA, Then I have to generate array from AA,AB,AC,AD.... to QA

Answer (score 0):

I really liked KrutPandya and PeterCsala's answer.

So this is just an improvement on their excellent idea.

```js
const numberToCol = (num) => {
     var str = '', q, r;
     while (num > 0) {
       q = (num - 1) / 26;
       r = (num - 1) % 26
       num = Math.floor(q)
       str = String.fromCharCode(65 + r) + str;
     }
  return str;
}

const colToNumber = col => 
  col.split('').reduce((code,chr,index) => code + (chr.charCodeAt() - 64) * (26 ** (col.length-index-1)),0)
;

const range = function* (start = 0, end = Infinity, step = 1) {
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step)
    yield i;
}

// Then 
Array.from(
  range(
    colToNumber('AA'), 
    colToNumber('AD')
  )
).map(numberToCol);

// range = [27,28,29,30] 
// map ['AA','AB','AC','AD']
```