# Convert Number to Corresponding Excel Column

Tags: excel, vsto, numbers, letter

I need some help in doing a logic that would convert a numeric value to corresponding MS Excel header value.

For example:

1 = "A"
2 = "B"
3 = "C"
4 = "D"
5 = "E"
.........
25 = "Y"
26 = "Z"
27 = "AA"
28 = "AB"
29 = "AC"
30 = "AD"
.........

Would appreciate some .NET codes (C# or VB) for this. Thanks.

Comment: Try the highest voted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa) (don't bother with the accepted answer...)

Comment: Depending on the context, try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837155/fastest-function-to-generate-excel-column-letters-in-c/837673#837673

Answer (score 1):

Here's some VBA (with test code) I strung together in Excel which does the trick. Unless VB.NET has changed drastically, it should work okay. Even if it has, you should be able to translate the *idea* into workable code.

```
' num2col - translate Excel column number (1-n) into column string ("A"-"ZZ"). '

Function num2col(num As Integer) As String
    ' Subtract one to make modulo/divide cleaner. '

    num = num - 1

    ' Select return value based on invalid/one-char/two-char input. '

    If num < 0 Or num >= 27 * 26 Then
        ' Return special sentinel value if out of range. '

        num2col = "-"
    Else
        ' Single char, just get the letter. '

        If num < 26 Then
            num2col = Chr(num + 65)
        Else
           ' Double char, get letters based on integer divide and modulus. '

           num2col = Chr(num \ 26 + 64) + Chr(num Mod 26 + 65)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

```
' Test code in Excel VBA. '

Sub main()
    MsgBox ("-  should be " & num2col(0))
    MsgBox ("A  should be " & num2col(1))
    MsgBox ("B  should be " & num2col(2))
    MsgBox ("Z  should be " & num2col(26))
    MsgBox ("AA should be " & num2col(27))
    MsgBox ("AB should be " & num2col(28))
    MsgBox ("AY should be " & num2col(51))
    MsgBox ("AZ should be " & num2col(52))
    MsgBox ("BA should be " & num2col(53))
    MsgBox ("ZY should be " & num2col(27 * 26 - 1))
    MsgBox ("ZZ should be " & num2col(27 * 26))
    MsgBox ("-  should be " & num2col(27 * 26 + 1))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string ColumnNumberToLetter(int ColumnNumber)
{
    if (ColumnNumber > 26)
    {
        return ((char) (Math.Floor(((double)ColumnNumber - 1) / 26) + 64)).ToString()
               + ((char) (((ColumnNumber - 1) % 26) + 65)).ToString();
    }
    return ((char)(ColumnNumber+64)).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static string ToExcelString(int number)
{
    if (number > 25)
    {
        int secondaryCounter = 0;
        while (number > 25)
        {
             secondaryCounter = secondaryCounter + 1;
             number = number - 25;
        }
        return ToExcelChar(number) + ToExcelChar(secondaryCounter);
    }
    else
    {
        return ToExcelChar(number)
    }
}
private const string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private static string ToExcelChar(int number)
{
    if (number > 25 || number < 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("the number passed in (" + number + ") must be between the range 0-25");
    }
    return alphabet[number];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a number base conversion routine. You want to convert from base 10 to base 26. Add each digit to 'A'

As in: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=271359

Comment: It isn't Base26, you'll be off a little.

Comment: Feeling confused now. What base is it? A-Z for each digit. Isn't that 26 possibilities?

Comment: @TheJacobTaylor Because you're missing `0` in that scheme.  One doesn't count `8, 9, 11, 12, ... 19, 21, 22 ...`  Remember that `A` is for `1`.  Incrementing Z by 1 should give you A0 (which isn't in this system), not AA.

Answer (score -1):

Just Use the activecell.address then manuipulate the string based on where the $ is to what you need.