# equivalent to Application.ConvertFormula in java (conversion b/w the excel A1 and R1C1 reference styles)

Tags: java, excel

folks.

My colleague at work **needs to convert between between the A1 and R1C1 reference styles** used in excel for reasons I don't really know much about. After searching has yielded no satisfactory results he's about to implement this conversion himself but he's still like thinking about efficiency of his approach. Ultimately he'll implement whatever he needs but maybe some of you are experts in the field of programming for excel and might know libraries (preferably in java) that have already methods for doing this conversion.

POI is not an option as they have not implemented this functionality AFAIK (trusting my colleague's experience).

Comment: Related question with various suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/837155/53614

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom realisation was implemented. i'd like to close this question.