# Incrementing alphabets

Tags: c#, alphabet

I am trying to create a function which will give me alphabet position when an index is passed. It will be same like how excel shows it's columns. A...Z, AA,AB.... I wrote the below function to get the results upto Z. It looks like

```
static string GetColumnName(int index)
{
    const int alphabetsCount = 26;
    if (index <= alphabetsCount)
    {
        int code = (index - 1) + (int)'A';
        return char.ConvertFromUtf32(code);
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

This works fine until 'Z'. It return 'A' if I pass 1 and return 'B' if I pass 2 and so on. But, I am not able to figure out how will I get AA when I pass 27 to this function. I guess I need a recursive method to find it.

Any inputs to this problem will be great!

**Edit**

This is suggested by Tordek. But his code will fail in numbers like 52, 78 etc. Added workaround for that and here is the final working code.

```
static string GetColumnName(int index)
{
    const int alphabetsCount = 26;

    if (index > alphabetsCount)
    {
        int mod = index % alphabetsCount;
        int columnIndex = index / alphabetsCount;

        // if mod is 0 (clearly divisible) we reached end of one combination. Something like AZ
        if (mod == 0)
        {
            // reducing column index as index / alphabetsCount will give the next value and we will miss one column.
            columnIndex -= 1;
            // passing 0 to the function will return character '@' which is invalid
            // mod should be the alphabets count. So it takes the last char in the alphabet.
            mod = alphabetsCount;
        }
        return GetColumnName(columnIndex) + GetColumnName(mod);
    }
    else
    {
        int code = (index - 1) + (int)'A';
        return char.ConvertFromUtf32(code);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any recursive function can be converted into an equivalent iterative one. I find it always easy to think recursively first:

```
static string GetColumnName(int index)
{
    const int alphabetsCount = 26;

    if (index > alphabetsCount) {
        return GetColumnName(index / alphabetsCount) + GetColumnName(index % alphabetsCount);
    } else {
        int code = (index - 1) + (int)'A';
        return char.ConvertFromUtf32(code);
    }
}
```

Which can be simple converted into:

```
static string GetColumnName(int index)
{
    const int alphabetsCount = 26;
    string result = string.Empty;

    while (index > 0) {
        result = char.ConvertFromUtf32(64 + (index % alphabetsCount)) + result;
        index /= alphabetsCount;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Even so, listen to Joel.

Comment: Great. My math is rusty. So couldn't figure out modulo operation. Thanks for the code.

Answer (score 4):

See this question:
[Translate a column index into an Excel Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297213/translate-an-index-into-an-excel-column-name)

or this one:
[How to convert a column number (eg. 127) into an excel column (eg. AA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa#182924)

Though the first link has a correct answer right at the top and the 2nd has several that are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is one possibility -- if `index > 26`, you deal with `index % 26` in this call and concatenate it to a recursive call on `index / 26`.  However, iteration is often speedier and not hard to arrange for simple cases such as this one.  In pseudocode:

```
string result = <convert `index % 26`>
while index > 26:
  index = index / 26
  result = <convert `index % 26`> + result
return result
```

or the like.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your pseudocode, but it's important to know that you should probably use the StringBuilder class if you're going to be appending to a string in a loop, to save on object allocations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(loband).aspx

Comment: This is wrong because it is not a base 26 system. If A would be 0, A would equal AA (0 == 00). If A would be 1, going from Z to AA would be like going from 9 to 11.

Comment: Paul, StringBuilder is overkill.  A 32-bit int is 2^32 and 26^7 overflows it so the max is 7 letters long.  7 iterations is hardly taxing.  A 64-bit long would only have 14 letters.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
static string GetColumnName(int index)
{
    const int alphabetsCount = 26;
    string result = '';

    if (index >= alphabetsCount)
    {
        result += GetColumnName(index-alphabetsCount)
    }
    return (string) (64 + index);
}
```

My C# is HORRIBLE AND RUSTY. Interpret this as pseudocode - it will almost certainly not compile, but may get you started.