# How to get excel name using RowNumber and ColumnNumber in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, excel

I want to know how can I get excel cell name like e.g. if I pass RowNumber and ColumnNumber
then function should return me the excel cell name like "A1".

Is it possible?

I am using ExcelWrapper which I found on codeplex.

Comment: This question is quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837155/fastest-function-to-generate-excel-column-letters-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the link from where I got answer 
[Translate a column index into an Excel Column Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297213/translate-an-index-into-an-excel-column-name)

And answer from that link is as follows

The answer I came up with is to get a little recursive. This code is in VB.Net:

```
Function ColumnName(ByVal index As Integer) As String
        Static chars() As Char = {"A"c, "B"c, "C"c, "D"c, "E"c, "F"c, "G"c, "H"c, "I"c, "J"c, "K"c, "L"c, "M"c, "N"c, "O"c, "P"c, "Q"c, "R"c, "S"c, "T"c, "U"c, "V"c, "W"c, "X"c, "Y"c, "Z"c}

        index -= 1 ''//adjust so it matches 0-indexed array rather than 1-indexed column

        Dim quotient As Integer = index \ 26 ''//normal / operator rounds. \ does integer division, which truncates
        If quotient > 0 Then
               ColumnName = ColumnName(quotient) & chars(index Mod 26)
        Else
               ColumnName = chars(index Mod 26)
        End If
End Function
```

And in C#:

```
string ColumnName(int index)
{
    index -= 1; //adjust so it matches 0-indexed array rather than 1-indexed column

    int quotient = index / 26;
    if (quotient > 0)
        return ColumnName(quotient) + chars[index % 26].ToString();
    else
        return chars[index % 26].ToString();
}
private char[] chars = new char[] {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
```

The only downside it that it uses 1-indexed columns rather than 0-indexed.