# How to make this custom worksheet initialization faster?

Tags: .net, performance, excel, office-interop

> **Summary**

This question is somehow the follow-up to this question:
[How to implement column self-naming from its index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160001/how-to-implement-column-self-naming-from-its-index)

Having tested the code provided in this above-linked question's answers, I finally encountered a serious performance issue.

> **Performance issue**

The performance issue occurs upon a Sheet initialization, that is, when I initialize the Sheet's Cells.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initialize an instance of the Company.Project.Sheet class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="nativeSheet">The native worksheet from which to initialize.</param>
    Friend Sub New(ByVal nativeSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
        _nativeSheet = nativeSheet
        Dim cells As IDictionary(Of String, ICell) = New Dictionary(Of String, ICell)()

        'These iterations hurt the performance of the API...'
        For rowIndex As Integer = 1 To _nativeSheet.Rows.Count Step 1
            For colIndex As Integer = 1 To _nativeSheet.Columns.Count Step 1
                Dim c As ICell = New Cell(_nativeSheet.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex))
                cellules.Add(c.Name, c)
            Next
        Next

        _cellules = New ReadOnlyDictionary(Of String, ICell)(cells)
    End Sub
```

> - **ReadOnlyDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)** : 
>     `A custom read-only dictionary that simply wraps a IDictionary(Of TKey, TValue) to prevent modifications.`
>
> **Discussion**

I'm working this way since each cell in an underlying spreadsheet worksheet is initialized from the initialization of the worksheet until the end, that is, when the worksheet is disposed or finalized. Hence, the same way I wish to initialize the cells of a Sheet, but I also wish to keep the performance boost of using the indexed cells over the named ("A1") cells, while keeping the ease of use to the API user to refer to a cell with its name, that is how I intend to use the dictionary, so that when I refer to cell "A1", I access this key into my dictionary and address the cell (1, 1) accordingly.

- Aside, I know of an even faster way to read from a worksheet using the Worksheet.UsedRange property that returns all of the used cells into a 2D matrix.
  If there was anyhow the same or about the same for the set of cells with which I could initialize multiple instances of my Cell class with, this would be great, and performant!
- I also thought of initializing like only a 100 x 100 matrix cells in memory while mapping them with my dictionary, as one will rarely use the whole sheet's cells. As such, I am still thinking of a way where I would have to access a not yet initialized cell, let's say Cells(120, 120). Ideally, I think, the program would have to initialize all the cells between the maximum initially initialized Cell(100, 100) until Cell (120, 120). Am I clear enough here? Feel free to ask for clarification! =)
- Another option could be that I only initialize the cells' names into the dictionary and keeping there row and column index in memory, not initializing a Cell instance with its nativeCell, say a Range. Here's the code of my Cell class to illustrate what I mean.

  ''' 
  ''' Represents a cell in a worksheet.
  ''' 
  ''' 
  Friend Class Cell
      Implements ICell

  ```
  Private _nativeCell As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
  Private _name As String

  ''' <summary>
  ''' Initializes a new instance of the Company.Project.Cell class.
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <param name="nativeCell">The Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range to wrap.</param>
  Friend Sub New(ByVal nativeCell As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)
      _nativeCell = nativeCell
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property NativeCell() As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Implements ICellule.NativeCell
      Get
          Return _nativeCell 
      End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property Column() As Integer Implements ICell.Column
      Get
          Return _nativeCell.Column
      End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property Row() As Integer Implements ICell.Row
      Get
          Return _nativeCell.Row
      End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String Implements ICellule.Name
      Get
          If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_name) OrElse _name.Trim().Length = 0) Then _
              _name = GetColumnName()

          Return _nom
      End Get
  End Property

  Public Property Value() As Object Implements ICellule.Value
      Get
          Return _nativeCell.Value2
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Object)
          _nativeCell.Value2 = value
      End Set
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property FormattedValue() As String Implements ICellule.FormattedValue
      Get
          Return _nativeCell.Text
      End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property NumericValue() As Double? Implements ICellule.NumericValue
      Get
          Return Value
      End Get
  End Property
  ```

> **Questions**

1. What are my other options?
2. Are there any other ways to walk through?
3. Is there a way I can make the actual approach viable as for performance concerns?

For your information, this issue timed out on testing, so the test never ended within an acceptable time range which actually take centuries...

Any thoughts are welcome! I'm open minded to other solutions or approach that will help me achieve this objective while addressing this performance issue.

Thanks to you all! =)

> **EDIT #1**

Thanks to [Maxim Gueivandov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574995/maxim-gueivandov), his solution solves the issue I have addressed in this question.

Aside, there's another problem that arose from this solution: `SystemOutOfMemoryException`, and that will be addressed in another question.

My Sincerest Thanks to Maxim Gueivandov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get all cells in the used range in one hop, thus avoiding to call `Cells(rowIndex, colIndex)` on each iteration of iteration (I guess that `Cells` hides an interop call, which may have a performance impact).

```
Dim usedRange As Range = nativeSheet.UsedRange
Dim cells(,) As Object = DirectCast(usedRange.get_Value( _
    XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault), Object(,))
[... do your row/col iterations ...]
```

You'll find some performance tips on which I based these assumptions in the following article: **[C# Excel Interop Use](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel)**. Most notably, check the benchmark part:

> === Excel interop benchmark in C# ===
>
> Cells[]:                 30.0 seconds
>
> get_Range(), Cells[]:    15.0 seconds
>
> UsedRange, get_Value():   1.5 seconds 
>   [fastest]

Comment: +1 I definitely agree with you and the benchmark you're presenting herewith. You're right saying that `usedRange` is the fastest possible way. Besides, my wish is to instantiate all of a worksheet's cells though they are not used. For instance, consider a new blank worksheet. The cells are instantiated though they are not used. Take Cells(200, 200), I don't remember having seen an Excel file with that much data in it. Though this cell is not used, the Range for it exists in memory. That is somehow what I wish either. So, is there a way similar to the `UsedRange` property to get all the cells?

Comment: @Will: How about **[nativeSheet.Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.cells.aspx)**?

Comment: The `Worksheet.Cells` property returns a `Range` object instance so that it can't be casted in an `Object(,)` array as the `Worksheet.UsedRange` will. Aside, I wonder whether it is viable as an approach. The idea of my architecture is to offer the users all of the flexibility delivered by the Excel Interop API while reducing its complexity, that is, making abstraction from the underlying spreadsheet API. I won't implement all of the properties contained in the Range class, for instance, while coding the most commonly used ones such as Value, Column, Row, Name.

Comment: (continue...) That is the purpose of the exposed NativeCell property within my ICell interface. So, when one wishes to extend his use of the library, he'll be able to to make it, otherwise, the properties proposed through my API shall make it easier to work with the underlying spreadsheet application. I've tried using the `Worksheet.Cells` property and iterating through the returned Range, but this is as slow as this was at first hand. I'm really beginning to think about implementing the Sheet.Cells property as an `Object(NativeSheet.Rows, NativeSheet.Columns)` array (to be continued...)

Comment: and using a batch-writing feature to output the information datum into the underlying spreadsheet, while using the `UsedRange` property when reading from a workbook. What do you think of it? Thanks for your time and the help provided.

Comment: @Will: Wait, `Worksheet.UsedRange` and `Worksheet.Cells` both return a Range object, don't they? Have you tried `nativeSheet.Cells.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)`?

Comment: My bad! It's a shame I didn't think of it. This works! Though there is something I didn't think of that exploded in my face: **`SystemOutOfMemoryException`**. I guess that I will have to walk another way around to obtain the desired behaviour, and that is for another question. Perhaps will you be albe to help again? Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: @Will: I may be wrong, but I guess that exception is due to the fact that `Worksheet.Cells` returns the maximum of cells an Excel sheet can contain (that is 65536 rows * 256 columns = 16777216 cells)? Unless you are using Office 2010 in which case the total cell count would be... over 1 million rows * 16,384 columns!

Comment: `Worksheet.Cells` effectively returns the maximum number of cells, and so that is the cause of the `SystemOutOfMemoryException`. The consequence is that I must rethink the architecture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183833/what-architecture-to-use-to-address-this-systemoutofmemoryexception-while-allowin