# Getting the Column name part in the address of an excel address

Tags: c#, excel

I have this bit of code to get the address of the last cell in my worksheet. It returns "$U$463", how can I get it to return just the U" part??

Rui Martins

```
Range newContracts = activeWorksheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell);

string address = newContracts.get_Address();
```

Comment: this question has some usable information  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297213/translate-an-index-into-an-excel-column-name?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string manipulation:

```
string columnLetter = address.Split('$', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
```

I would rather use the column's index number instead of its letter; you can get this from the `Column` property.  If you really need the letter identifier, you can calculate it.  I'm sure I remember a built-in function for converting a column's index number (i.e., 3) to its letter identifier (i.e., "C"), but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been trying to get, some function that did it. The string manipulation is easy, I just wanted to do it differently.

Comment: @ruimartins I think I found what I was looking for: the `ConvertFormula` function.  But I can't get it to return just the letter `"D"` for the fourth column; it always returns `"$D:$D"`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RegularExpression or the Substring method like so:

```
string rowId = address.Substring(address.LastIndexOf('$') + 1);
string columnId = address.Substring(1, address.LastIndexOf('$') - 1);
```