# Variable of source of data for chart In Excel With VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I’m using Excel 2007 VBA to create a ScatterSmoothNoMarkers type chart in the same data sheet. My source data are depended on a number of text files opened. The Xvalue is fixed @ location A2: A200. And ID of columns of Series value will be changed.

If I opens 2files, my source data will be:  `Range(A2:A200, F2:G200)`.  To open 3files, my source data will be:  `Range(A2:A200, H2:J200)`
And so on… So I need to replace those ID of columns by variables. But I got an error when I set the source of data.
Here is my code:

```
Sub addChart()
Dim n as integer ‘files count and also the number of columns for chart1 
Dim intColStart, intColStop as integer  ‘number of columns for chart 1
intColStart = n*2+2  ‘this is a formula to find the ID of the start column of chart1
intColStop = n*3+1  ‘this is a formula to find the ID of the stop column of chart1
…..
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add _
         (Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
        .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A200, intColStart:intColStop ")  ‘’’’’PROBLEM RIGHT HERE‘’’’’’’
        .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
……..
End With
End Sub
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference variables within `"` marks. VBA doesn't know to convert them and so it thinks you are setting a `Range` including text which you are literally attempting to use

```
A2:A200, intColStart:intColStop
```

which does not make any sense to VBA.

Why not change line

```
    .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A200, intColStart:intColStop ")
```

to

```
    .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(2,2), Cells(200,intColStop))
```

---

If I'm misunderstanding your interest, I would suggest something where you manually create the `Range` `String` input - using something like the following:

```
dim rngStr as String
dim firstColStr as String
dim secondColStr as String
firstColStr = ColumnLetter(intColStart)
secondColStr = ColumnLetter(intColStop)
rngStr = "A2:A200," & firstColStr & ":2:" & secondColStr & "200"
...

.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(rngStr)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4695873/1048539) defines the function `ColumnLetter` I am referencing above (which gets the letter from the index).

Comment: Many thanks Felix and Enderland for your help. I used Endeland's input to create to ColumnLetter and it worked. It saved me a lot of time. I will try Felix's later on.